# @import url(addonstyles.css) still relevant?

Tags: css

I know it is used to hide addonstyles.css from some old browsers.

Well, apart from that,

is there any other usage for this?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason given for using @import instead (or along with)  is because older browsers didn't recognize @import, so you could hide styles from them.

Another use for the @import method is to use multiple style sheets on a page, but only one link in your . For example, a corporation might have a global style sheet for every page on the site, with sub-sections having additional styles that only apply to that sub-section. By linking to the sub-section style sheet and importing the global styles at the top of that style sheet, you don't have to maintain a gigantic style sheet with all the styles for the site and every sub-section. The only requirement is that any @import rules need to come before the rest of your style rules.